# Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony-flex

I am actually building an API based on:

- symfony/flex: v1.0.61
- symfony: v4.0.3
- api-platform/api-pack: v1.0.1
- api-platform/core: v2.1.4

The CRUD operations were easy to implement. Nevertheless, the 
[custom operation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers) does not seem to be straightforward.

The custom operation I am trying to implement will simply return a `App\Entity\Product` based on a given `$slug`.

- the route is: `/api/products/by-slugs/{slug}`
- the method is: `GET`
- the operation type is: `itemOperations`

This is how things are being done:

**The declaration of the Product resource**

```
<?php
// src/Entity/Product
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"pagination_client_items_per_page"=true,
 *                          "filters"={"product.search"}
 *                         },
 *              collectionOperations={
 *                      "get"={
 *                      "method"="GET",
 *                      "normalization_context"={"groups"={"product_gets"}} },
 *                      "post"={
 *                      "method"="POST",
 *                      "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"product_post"}} }
 *              },
 *              itemOperations={
 *                      "get"={
 *                      "method"="GET",
 *                      "normalization_context"={"groups"={"product_get"}} },
 *                      "put"={
 *                      "method"="PUT",
 *                      "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"product_put"}} },
 *                      "delete"={
 *                      "method"="DELETE"},
 *                      "product_slug"={"route_name"="route_product_slug"}
 *              })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */

class Product{
}
```

**The declaration of the ProductLoader**

```
<?php

namespace App\Loader;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface;

class ProductLoader {
    private $em;
    private $logger;
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $em,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        CacheItemPoolInterface $cache){
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    public function findBySlug($slug){
        return $this->em->getRepository(Product::class)->findProductBySlug($slug);
    }
}
```

**The declaration of the ProductRepository**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * ProductRepository
 */
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findProductBySlug($slug) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("b")
                ->where("b.slug = :slug")
                ->setParameter('slug', $slug);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }

}
```

**The declaration of the custom operation in a Symfony controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

use App\Loader\ProductLoader;
use App\Entity\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="route_product_slug",
     *     path="/api/products/by-slug/{slug}",
     *     defaults={"_api_resource_class"=Product::class,
     *               "_api_item_operation_name"="product_slug"
     *     }
     * )
     * @Method("GET")
     */
     public function productsGetBySlugAction(ProductLoader $productLoader, $slug){
        return $productLoader->findBySlug($slug);
     }
}
```

A quick run of the command below returned:

```
bin/console debug:router
 --------------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ --------------------------------------- 
  Name                                    Method   Scheme   Host   Path                                   
 --------------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ --------------------------------------- 
  app_product_products                    ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                      
  route_product_slug                      GET      ANY      ANY    /api/products/by-slug/{slug}           
  api_entrypoint                          ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/{index}.{_format}                 
  api_doc                                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/docs.{_format}                    
  api_jsonld_context                      ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/contexts/{shortName}.{_format}    
  api_products_get_collection             GET      ANY      ANY    /api/products.{_format}                
  api_products_post_collection            POST     ANY      ANY    /api/products.{_format}                
  api_products_get_item                   GET      ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_products_put_item                   PUT      ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_products_delete_item                DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/products/{id}.{_format}           
  api_regions_get_collection              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/regions.{_format}                 
  api_regions_post_collection             POST     ANY      ANY    /api/regions.{_format}                 
  api_regions_get_item                    GET      ANY      ANY    /api/regions/{id}.{_format}            
  api_regions_put_item                    PUT      ANY      ANY    /api/regions/{id}.{_format}            
  api_regions_delete_item                 DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/regions/{id}.{_format}            
  api_countries_get_collection            GET      ANY      ANY    /api/countries.{_format}               
  api_countries_post_collection           POST     ANY      ANY    /api/countries.{_format}               
  api_countries_get_item                  GET      ANY      ANY    /api/countries/{id}.{_format}          
  api_countries_put_item                  PUT      ANY      ANY    /api/countries/{id}.{_format}          
  api_countries_delete_item               DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/countries/{id}.{_format}          
  api_countries_regions_get_subresource   GET      ANY      ANY    /api/countries/{id}/regions.{_format}  
  _twig_error_test                        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}               
  _wdt                                    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                          
  _profiler_home                          ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                            
  _profiler_search                        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                      
  _profiler_search_bar                    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar                  
  _profiler_phpinfo                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                     
  _profiler_search_results                ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results      
  _profiler_open_file                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                        
  _profiler                               ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                     
  _profiler_router                        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router              
  _profiler_exception                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception           
  _profiler_exception_css                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css       
 --------------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ---------------------------------------
```

The route `route_product_slug` is well existing but I am always getting the following error:

**Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type App\Entity\Product**"

```
{
"@context": "/sf-flex-40/public/index.php/api/contexts/Error",
"@type": "hydra:Error",
"hydra:title": "An error occurred",
"hydra:description": "Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\Product\"",
"trace": [
    {
        "namespace": "",
        "short_class": "",
        "class": "",
        "type": "",
        "function": "",
        "file": "/home/amine/docker-projects/sf-flex-40/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Routing/IriConverter.php",
        "line": 107,
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Bridge\\Symfony\\Routing",
        "short_class": "IriConverter",
        "class": "ApiPlatform\\Core\\Bridge\\Symfony\\Routing\\IriConverter",
        "type": "->",
        "function": "getIriFromItem",
        "file": "/home/amine/docker-projects/sf-flex-40/vendor/api-platform/core/src/JsonLd/Serializer/ItemNormalizer.php",
        "line": 71,
        "args": [
            [
                "object",
                "App\\Entity\\Product"
            ]
        ]
    },
```

This error seems to be recurrent. Nevertheless, I am asking again since the problem seems to be related to bad order of routes in my flex-enable symfony 4 application (please refer to https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/830).

So, how can set the proper order of the routes if I am using the annotations in symfony 4. The routes are defined in these files:

**The first file: annotations.yaml**

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

**The second file: api_platform.yaml**

```
# config/routes/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api
```

Does this mean I have to configure all my work with YAML file in stead of annotations so that I can specify the order of the route?

Thanks

Here what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of the route of the custom operation can only be through **yaml file**. In fact, the use of annotation will not us to get **the correct order of routes**. The route of the custom operation must come after the declaration of the route `api_platform`.

```
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api

api_product_slug:
    path: '/api/products/by-slug/{slug}'
    methods:  ['GET']
    defaults:
        _controller: App\Controller\ProductController:productsGetBySlugAction
        _api_resource_class: 'App\Entity\Product'
        _api_collection_operation_name: 'product_slug'
```